# Spring social twitter, fetched profile returns null email (app whitelisted)

Tags: spring, email, spring-mvc, twitter, spring-social

I'm trying to add "Sign in with Twitter" thing to my web application. I configured spring security and social and everything works i.e. I can fetch user name, access key, secret etc., but when I want to get user email from fetched profile I'm getting null.

My code inside of controller (spring redirect to this after successful authorization) looks like this:

```
Connection<A> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);   
String email = connection.fetchUserProfile().getEmail();
```

I know you have to whitelist application, check "Request email addresses from users" field, refresh tokens etc. I did that all already and still getting null. I'm out of ideas what to do, I tried "/auth/twitter?scope=email" instead of "/auth/twitter" but does not work. Maybe it's something wrong with Spring?
I'm using newest spring-social 1.1.4 with spring twitter API 1.1.2.

I saw many question about this issue but all of them were from 2011/2012, AFAIK Twitter didn't support fetching email address from user back then, but it changed, however it still doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 6):

There is an Open issue regarding for this.

See [getEmail of org.springframework.social.connect.UserProfile returns null even if additional permissions granted](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-twitter/issues/97).

As a workaround you can use the `RestTemplate` which you can grab from `TwitterTemplate` and make rest call to "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true".

Some thing like this:

```
private TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate;

[....]

RestTemplate restTemplate = twitterTemplate.getRestTemplate();   
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true", String.class);
System.out.println("Profile Info with Email: "+ response);
```

Check this [Commit](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/commit/920260eef4419e069bd1b4d0bf2810a06d5ba536) in my GitHub Spring Twitter experiments project for getting email of User.

Answer (score 0):

============In twitter application management============

step 1.check select "Request email addresses from users"

step 2.Permission set ReadOnly.

============edit your social-login-twitter code============

step 3.TwitterProfile.java  add email field.

step 4.set UserTemplate.java's  getUserProfile method :

```
return restTemplate.getForObject(buildUri("account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true"), TwitterProfile.class);
```

step 5.set TwitterAdapter.java's fetchUserProfile method:

```
return new UserProfileBuilder().setName(profile.getName()).setUsername(profile.getScreenName()).setEmail(profile.getEmail()).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using hint from Sanjay's answer

```
       private TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate;

       twitterTemplate = new TwitterTemplate("Your App's Consumer Key", "Your App's Consumer Secret",connection.createData().getAccessToken(), connection.createData().getSecret());

       RestTemplate restTemplate = twitterTemplate.getRestTemplate();
       String response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true", String.class);

      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
      System.out.println(json.getString("email"));
```